# how to shuffle the array value

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I want to display the array value in shuffled manner.

Eg:

Now I am getting array values from database as

```
   <?php foreach($question as $article) {
      $a[]= $article->answer;
     echo"<pre>";
     print_r($a);
    } ?> 



 Array
   (
    [0] => Language
    [1] => 26
    [2] => 7
    [3] => English
    [4] => English
    [5] => English
    [6] => dsfd
   )
```

and values displays as button in

```
Language
 26
 7
 English
 English
 English
 dsfd
```

But I need to Display in Shuffle as

```
 26
 English
 English
  dsfd
  7
 English
 Language
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Did you even checked the documentation? The answer is really obvious ...

Comment: Typing your question's title into Google tells you the answer :S

Answer (score 0):

There is a php function with this name which does exatcly that :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Answer (score 0):

try

```
shuffle($a)
print_r($a);
```

this will shuffle the array

Comment: why do you have the `print_r`? It is not necessary for shuffling and only displays if the shuffling was successful.

Comment: as long as he is receiving an array, it will be successful and the print_r is to show his array shuffled

Comment: `shuffle`  returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` so `print_r` will display `1` or nothing, but not the shuffled array.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
    $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    shuffle($array);
    die(var_dump($array));
?>
```

Return Values.
Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
bool shuffle ( array &$array )
```

example

```
shuffle($a);
```

You can use print_r after that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function below. Pass an array with key/value pairs to the function and it will shuffle the array keeping the values and keys intact.

```
function shuffle_assoc($array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    shuffle($keys);

    $result = array();
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        $result[$k] = $array[$k];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

OR use `shuffle($keys);` for a normal array